# IE8 Links Text and Clickable area do not match when zooming

Tags: ie8-compatibility-mode

I have encountered a strange problem with IE8 that is:
the location of link differes from where mouse icon changes to hand(&clickalbe)
stack overflow would not let me post photos ...
but assume a "buy" linke that gets underline when mouse moves over empty space near it! but not when mouse is over the "buy" text! similar problem with other links in this page. it is a simple  tag. no overlapping DIVs or any thing with JavaScript on that empty space. here is the HTML

```
<td nowrap="1" align="Right"><a href="http://someurl" onmouseout="window.status=''; return true" onmouseover="window.status='Buy the selected Stock'; return true">
   Buy</a>&nbsp;|......
```

simple Link in a  tag. 
this happens only when all these conditions exist
1. In some zoom levels only 
2. only when Page is inside a Frameset (does not have problem when loaded seperately)
3. only when Compatibility mode is not in use

I've not been able to replicate problem on any other server except our Production servers which I do not have any kind of access to as a developer. it will not appear on your browser even if I give you all our sources!
I just look for some hints if you had similar problem. 
thank you